# Need help in Pivot

Tags: sql-server-2014, pivot

I am using sql server 2014

I wanted to get Id (identity) field for maximum date as per order status id

Customer - Order Table:

Id (identity) | Customer ID | Order Status ID | Order Date

```
10000     |   11        |   1             |  1 Feb 2017
10001     |   11        |   2             |  2 Feb 2017
10002     |   11        |   2             |  3 Feb 2017
10003     |   11        |   3             |  4 Feb 2017
10004     |   11        |   3             |  5 Feb 2017
```

Expected Result

```
Customer ID |     1 |    2 |     3
11          | 10000 |10002 | 10004
```

Comment: You need to state (in the question tags) which database engine you are using. Some support `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` directly, some have equivalent functions as extensions, and some require you to perform the process more manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/info

Comment: I am using sql server 2014

Comment: Has `Order Status ID` a well-known different values? f.e. 1,2,3 or is it variable.

Comment: These are status id for order - 1:order request 2:order confirm 3:order shipped.There multiple entries as order confirm by 2 level of hierarchy in seller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for this solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [Customer ID], [Order Status ID], rmax = MAX(Id)
    FROM OrderTable
    GROUP BY [Customer ID], [Order Status ID]
) A
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(rmax) FOR
    [Order Status ID] IN ([1],[2],[3])
) A_pvt
```